# JBOSS-EAP-6.4 How to reference class present inside EAR when parent class is loaded from global module

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to deploy my EAR in `JBOSS-EAP-6.4` and if I deploy it normally i.e. placing all my jars and dependent jars inside EAR, it loads successfully.

Just to explain, I have my `custom.jar` which is referencing other product jars packaged in EAR and these are loaded from EAR only.

Now for debugging purpose, I changed one class in `custom.jar` and deployed it as global module. Deployment of my EAR is failing because it cannot find class definition, which is present in EAR and referenced by `custom.jar`.

In `Jboss-eap-5`, I used to do similar debugging by putting my `custom.jar` inside `<jboss-eap-5_home>/server/<domain>/lib`.

One Approach which I can think off is to create a module of all the product jars and reference this module in global `module.xml` but I would prefer if I could refer EAR/lib jars instead.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @tiitrfma ?

Comment: @sampada, I am working on another issue . I will try to create a global module with all the jars and then test it.